# Homebrew install older packages

Tags: homebrew

When searching for an older version of a package - specifically phantomjs 1.9.8 - with Homebrew on Mac, it returns:

> If you meant "phantomjs" specifically:
>
> It was migrated from caskroom/cask to homebrew/core.

Is there a way to get older versions?

I'm on homebrew version 1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

I don't see alternative versions from my side.

```
> brew search phantomjs
==> Searching local taps...
phantomjs
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
```

But in principle, if there are

```
> brew search gnupg
==> Searching local taps...
gnupg                             gnupg-pkcs11-scd                   gnupg@1.4                         gnupg@2.0
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
homebrew/php/php53-gnupg                       homebrew/php/php55-gnupg                       homebrew/php/php70-gnupg
homebrew/php/php54-gnupg                       homebrew/php/php56-gnupg                       homebrew/php/php71-gnupg
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
```

you'd install it by specifying the version

```
> brew install gnupg@1.4
```

Comment: Ok, so maybe there is just the one version. I though maybe you needed to do something to search `homebrew/core`